# Low tech solution to crush chicken bones effortlessly

Tags: food, substitute-tool

I am looking for ideas for some kind of device that I could build from simple elements (wood, stainless steel screws, bolt for axle) and possibly some woodworking (I have a router) in order to assist me crush chicken bones.

I like this device:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlkQly2T-Wc

[image]

but I was thinking of something more agressive, by having the screws protrude more from the rotor, and another layer of screws on the vertical panel to provide a good shredding action, and a high torque with the help of reduction gears. Would this be a good starting point ? I'm not sure which force is required to break chicken bones..

Comment: It looks like an instrument of torture, I hope you won't put someones fingers inside

Comment: How finely do you want then crushed?

Comment: I'm not sure that you're looking for a life hack, more like the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Carl I agree. Life hacks are supposed to be about common, everyday problems. I have never needed to crush chicken bones more efficiently, and I suspect I'm not the only one.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Where can I find what's on topic lifehacks ?

Comment: @AntoineLecaille At the top of the page there's a tiny "Help" link. Click that, then select "Tour". Or just use this link: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about something like a big corkscrew as core, but when searching for pictures to illustrate my point I came upon ice crushing machines that might do the trick:
[image: Leopold Vienna Ice Crusher]

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Leopold-Vienna-Ice-Crusher-Transparent/dp/B0000AQVOG

Comment: I like the shape of the teeth. I'll make a small scale experiment with just one tooth and scale up if it's working..